# Посчитать количество слов в строке, разбив строку используя boost::split

Tags: c++, boost

Получилось как-то так, и, собственно, не очень понятно, каким образом заполняется вектор. И как учесть любое количество пробелов?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main ()
{
    printf("stroka = ");
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    vector<string> words;
    split(words, s, is_any_of(" "));

    printf("%lu", words.size());

}
```

Также хотелось бы увидеть на примерах использование библиотек

boost/algorithm/string.hpp
и
boost/container/vector.hpp

киньте ссылок по-возможности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было в использовании аргумента token_compress_on для split

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main ()
{
    printf("stroka = ");
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    string s_copy = trim_copy(s);

    vector<string> words;
    split(words, s_copy, is_any_of(" "), token_compress_on);

    printf("%lu\n", words.size());

    for (auto it = words.begin(); it < words.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

}
```

Теперь при вводе строки, например:

```
"   asd     qwe            asdqwe  "
```

Выводится:

```
3
asd
qwe
asdqwe
```

Может кому-то поможет.

Answer (score -1):

Например можно написать такой класс

```
using namespace std;
class Str_tokens {
    vector<string> v;
public:
    Str_tokens(const string &s = "")
    {
        typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string>  I;

        std::istringstream  is(s);
        std::copy( I(is), I(), std::back_inserter(v));
    }
    string& operator [](size_t n)   {
        if (n < v.size())
            return v[n];
        return v.back();
    }

    size_t size() const    { return v.size(); }

};
```

тогда и можем заполнять контейнеры словами из строки

```
int main()
{   
    Str_tokens v("using namespace std;");
    vector<string> words;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        words.emplace_back(v[i]);
// дальше можно  одинаково использовать  слова из words и из обьекта v

    return 0;
}
```

можно конечно и по другому - я лишь привел пример

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Интересный вариант. Но задача состоит в том, чтобы разобраться с boost'ом)

Comment: вам было не понятно каким образом заполняется вектор. А чтобы смотреть примеры использования библиотеки, прогуглите. Никто не будет сидеть здесь и писать для вас примеры

Comment: Я, как бы, и просил ссылки, а не сидеть и нарешивать для меня примеры. Спасибо Вам еще раз и прекратим эту полемику.